There is a permutation matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{T}$ is in this form for symmetric $A$
Suppose that $A$ is a real matrix and is symmetric and nonzero, then I want to prove that there is a permutation matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{T}=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
B & E^{\top} \\
E & C
\end{array}\right]$, where $B$ is either a real number or a $2\times 2$ nonsingular matrix, I want to prove this but I don't know where to start

Just to be clear, can B be a matrix within the matrix, or is P the non-singular matrix?

@RedFive P is just a permutation matrix and B is nonsingular

OK thanks. This is what I thought, but wanted to double check before going any further.

What if $A = \pmatrix{i & i\cr i & i\cr}$?

@RobertIsrael A is real, I forget to say this

Why not just select $P=I$? Since $A$ is symmetric the result trivially follows. Am I missing something?

@obareey B,C may not to be assumed to be symmetric

@YuerCauchy $B$, $C$ must be symmetric since $PAP^T$ is symmetric.
